# Python3: remove a substring between two delimiting char

Tags: python, python-3.x, substring

I am looking for a clean solution in Python3 to cut a substring out of a string (like an inline comment). However,if it is an odd number of  seperators, then the rest of the text shall be removed (like a remark at the end of a programming line)

input:

```
s="abcd;efghij;kl;mn"
```

output:

```
s="abcdkl"
```

How can this be done in a similar way like .replaceAll in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have two separator you can use `str.split()` as following:

```
In [15]: sp = s.split(';')

In [18]: result = sp[0] + sp[-1]

In [19]: result
Out[19]: 'abcdklmn'
```

Otherwise, based on your string and expected result you can use regular expressions to find the desired sub-strings.

Demo:

```
In [25]: s
Out[25]: 'abcd;efghij;klmn'

In [26]: re.sub(r'(;[^;]*)?;', '', s)
Out[26]: 'abcdklmn'

In [27]: s="abcd;klmn"

In [28]: re.sub(r'(;[^;]*)?;', '', s)
Out[28]: 'abcdklmn'
```

Comment: there is a side-effect of your solution: if there are no or only one  seperator in the string, then the input string gets doubled concatinated

Comment: @MarcelSonderegger What's your expected results in those cases? If you just want to remove the separator in case there's one and return the original string in case with no delimiter, you can simply use `str.replace` to replace the delimiter if there's any. This is however the downside of split approach over a regex-based approach. In this case you're code won't be efficiently automated.

Comment: However, if it is an odd number of  seperators, then the rest of the text shall be removed. (see question: I adapted it). Efficency of code is not important only beauty.

Answer (score 3):

**@Marcel**, as you are satisfied with the above approach suggested by **@Kasramvd**, it is good and  I want to suggest you to write a simple tiny function using `lambda` keyword.

Call it multiple times with new parameters and get the output as the below code shows.

> Visit and check https://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php for detailed examples.
>
> See [Python lambda function](http://thepythonguru.com/python-lambda-function/) for brief knowledge.

```
>>> get_string = lambda s: s.split(';')[0] + s.split(';')[-1]
>>>
>>> get_string("abcd;efghij;klmn")
'abcdklmn'
>>>
>>> get_string("ABCD;MONKEY;XYZ")
'ABCDXYZ'
>>>
>>> get_string("PYTHON;abcd;LEARN")
'PYTHONLEARN'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using a regexp:

```
import re
delimiters = ';'
s = 'fsdfsd;sfdsfd;ffs'
reg_exp = "[" + delimiters + "].*[" + delimiters + "]"
new_s = re.sub(reg_exp, "", s)
print (new_s)
```